# How to implement dynamic rules functionality in PyFlink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, pyflink

My aim is to implement dynamic rule based validation of a streaming dataset. My project is using Pyflink. I know that there is a Broadcast pattern in Flink, but didnt find any credible info with regards to the same in Python. Is this feature available in Pyflink ?. If not is there any workaround to implement dynamic rules in Pyflink

Comment: Did you ever find the functionality in Pyflink to do this?